# I want the hyperlink to be in a different place

Tags: html, css

I am looking to put the hyperlink in a different place. How can I move the google.com link to another place on the page?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>Randy's first html web page !</title>
<style type="text/css">
body
{background-image:url('Koala.gif');} 
h1
{
text-align:center; 
font-size:500%;
}
h2
{
text-align:center;
font-size:250%;
}
p
{
text-align:center;
font-size:200%;
color:#00fff0;
}
div
{
background-color:#efffff;
}
a 
{
text-align:center;
}
th
{
background-color:green;
}
tr  
{
background-color:green;
}
table 
{ 
width: 200px; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto; 
}
</style>
</head>
<h1> Hello Professor</h1>
<h2> By: Randy White</h2>
<P> It's getting better as the term goes on.</P> 
<P>Week 2</P>
<P><img src="Hydrangeas.jpg" width="150" height="100" alt="Hydrangeas.jpg"></P> 
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Day</th>
<th>Year</th>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>December</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>2010</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <a href="http://www.google.com">Visit Google!</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In short: CTRL-x, CTRL-v

Comment: no joke I am new to css and I am getting better but I still have a few problems

Comment: By cutting/pasting it elsewhere in the document?

Comment: maybe I am not explaining correctly. I would like for it to be in the center of the html page. Right now the link is on the far bottom right corner of the page I would like to have it in the center of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS, add this:

```
#google-link {
    text-align: center;
}
```

This aligns text inside in the center.

In your HTML, change the Google link to this:

```
<div id="google-link"><a href="http://www.google.com">Visit Google!</a></div>
```

The div is tagged with the google-link id, which gets it the above style.  The style actually affects the contents of the div, aligning them to the center.  The div itself is the width of the page.

Comment: @randy: You're lucky anything works.  You're missing an opening <body> tag

Comment: Would you look at that, he is.  Good catch, @Gerrat - I completely glossed over that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are interested about css positioning. Take a look at this: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: +1 because of great resource for beginners!! I wish I had found this before!

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your html is missing an opening < body> tag!
2. add "text-align:center;" to your css for the body tag.